# Programmatically check Cloud firestore read/write count

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to check the read or write count depending on the call made by the code. For instance, let's say I have

```
final ref = Firestore.instance.document('users/uid');
ref.get();
```

Now that this is 1 read operation, and I can use

```
ref.delete()
```

or

```
ref.setData(data);
```

etc.

This is easy for single operations, how about I am listening for a `Stream`, how do I know how many read/write operations are taking place by my function calls?

Comment: You are planing to show this to the user? or just wanted to know about it?

Comment: You need to add ```onCreate() & onUpdate()``` to get keep count of writes in a location in Realtime database. And regarding read, wherever you have any code that read any value, just add few more lines of code which increments that READ value stored in firebase realtime database by 1. This should be the easiest approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if it's a stream, or iterating an array, or any other form of consumption.  Once the query hits the server, you are charged for the number of documents returned by that query, regardless of how you choose to iterate them.  They show up in the client app all at the same time, and you get to choose how to deal with them.

For realtime listeners, you are charged a read for each document that gets delivered to your snapshot listener.  Again, it doesn't matter what you do with the documents after that - the cost is already paid.

Comment: Got it sir, and does it really matter if my `Map` data in `setData` is small or big, I'll be charged same amount, right?

Comment: There is nothing in the documentation on billing that suggests are you charged on the size of a write, just the number of documents written.  Ingress is free.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing